# Usage of an atomic variable within threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, stdatomic

Consider a program with three threads A,B,C.

They have a shared global object G.

I want to use an atomic variable(i) inside G which is written by Thread B and Read by A.

My approach was:

declare i in G as:

```
std::atomic<int> i;
```

write it from thread B using a pointer to G as:

```
G* pG; //this is available inside A and B 

pG->i = 23;
```

And read it from thread A using the same way.

```
int k = pG->i;
```

Is my approach correct if these threads try to access this variable simultaneously.?

Comment: How correct would your program be if thread A would be reading the value before B would be writing it?

Comment: @JVApen Thread A will take the available (initialized) value which is acceptable..

Comment: In that case, accessing i from 2 threads is correct. When accessing it, one of the threads will be first and the other will see the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like JV says, it depends what your definition of "correct" is.  See http://preshing.com/20120612/an-introduction-to-lock-free-programming/.  If it doesn't need to synchronize with anything, you should use `std::memory_order_relaxed` stores instead of the default sequential consistency stores, so it compiles to more efficient asm (no memory barrier instructions).

But yes, accessing an atomic struct member through a pointer is fine, as long as the pointer itself is initialized before the threads start.

If the struct is a global, then don't use a pointer to it, just access the global directly.  Having a separate variable that always points to the same global is an extra level of indirection for no benefit.

If you want to change the pointer, it also needs to be `std::atomic<struct foo *> pG`, and changing it gets complicated as far as deciding when it's safe to free the old data after changing it.